# Python equivalent of the R operator "%in%"

Tags: python, r, pandas

What is the python equivalent of this in operator?  I am trying to filter down a pandas database by having rows only remain if a column in the row has a value found in my list.

I tried using any() and am having immense difficulty with this.

Comment: @Jeff post that as an answer.

Comment: That's beautiful, exactly what I was looking for.  You know how hard it is to google "in" and special symbols.

Comment: I don't see the difficulty. Googling "pandas in operator" provides http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html as first hit and a text search of "in operator" on that page let's you immediately find what you are looking for.

Comment: I googled Python rather than pandas, I didn't know it was a Pandas specific thing.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Pandas comparison with R docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_r.html#match).

```
s <- 0:4
s %in% c(2,4)
```

The `isin` method is similar to R %in% operator:

```
In [13]: s = pd.Series(np.arange(5),dtype=np.float32)

In [14]: s.isin([2, 4])
Out[14]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 13):

FWIW: without having to call pandas, here's the answer using a `for loop` and `list compression` in pure python

```
x = [2, 3, 5] 
y = [1, 2, 3]

# for loop
for i in x: [].append(i in y)

Out: [True, True, False]


# list comprehension
[i in y for i in x]

Out: [True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use only `numpy` without `panads` (like a use case I had) then you can:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 10])
y = np.array([10, 11, 2])
np.isin(y, x)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
c(10, 11, 2) %in% c(1, 2, 3, 10)
```

Note that the last line will work only for `numpy >= 1.13.0`, for older versions you'll need to use `np.in1d`.

Answer (score -2):

As others indicate, `in` operator of base Python works well.

```
myList = ["a00", "b000", "c0"]

"a00" in myList
# True

"a" in myList
# False
```

Comment: But requires an atomic left side to yield results that match R's `%in%` in calling semantics.  E.g. `["a00", "node", "c0"] in myList` isn't what someone used to %in% is going to expect.