# An equivalent to R's %in% operator in Python

Tags: python, r

I'm starting to learn a bit more about Python.  One function I often want but don't know how to program/do in Python is the `x %in% y` operator in R.  It works like so:

```
1:3 %in% 2:4

##[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The first element in `x` (1) has no match in `y` so `FALSE` where as the last two elements of `x` (2 & 3) do have a match in `y` so they get `TRUE`.

Not that I expected this to work as it wouldn't have worked in R either but using `==` in Python I get:

```
[1, 2, 3] == [2, 3, 4]
# False
```

How could I get the same type of operator in Python?  I'm not tied to base Python if such an operator already exists elsewhere.

Comment: Would that be `[x in range(2,5) for x in range(1,4)]` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206376/python-equivalent-of-the-r-operator-in

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The other question asks for a panda-specific solution and  the answer has nothing to do with general concept of 'in'.

Comment: Could do `for i in x: [].append(i in y)` or `[i in y for i in x]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%in%` is simply `in` in Python. But, like most other things in Python outside numpy, it’s not vectorised:

```
In [1]: 1 in [1, 2, 3]
Out[1]: True

In [2]: [1, 2] in [1, 2, 3]
Out[2]: False
```

Answer (score 3):

It's actually very simple.

```
if/for element in list-like object.
```

Specifically, when doing so for a list it will compare every element in that list. When using a dict as the list-like object (iterable), it will use the dict keys as the object to iterate through.

Cheers

Edit:
For your case you should make use of "List Comprehensions".

```
[True for element in list1 if element in list2]
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your answer — `if element in list-like object` and `for element in list-like object` are two fundamentally different operations in Python. The second one performs *iteration*, not a membership test. The first one performs the membership test (see my answer) but the `if` isn’t part of the syntax.

Comment: I know. I just wanted to demonstrate other uses of the 'in' keyword.

Comment: Good use of `if`. Plus one.